# Can Cognito Forms be saved and printed?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can Cognito Forms be saved to the user's computer and printed?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do not have the ability for a user to save a form to a users computer we are working on the ability to Save and Resume a form they are working on. We hope to have this feature out by the end of the next month(May). You can follow our progress of this feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/Bk6swilY).